# How can I get data from a Heroku PostgreSQL database from a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, google-cloud-functions

Google does not offer a free PostgreSQL instance, but Heroku does. Because of that, I am wanting to use GCP for everything except the database. Is there any way to connect to a Heroku database from a Google Cloud Function?

I am new to Google Cloud and am familiar with creating and hosting Express apps. I know that with Express, packages like Massive can be used to establish connections like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const massive = require("massive");
const { CONNECTION_STRING } = process.env;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

massive({
  connectionString: CONNECTION_STRING,
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
})
  .then((databaseInstance) => {
    app.set("database", databaseInstance);
    console.log(gradientString.pastel("DB Connected"));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

but because there is no server, I am not sure how I would go about calling a Heroku database from a Cloud Function. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is not much different in cloud functions. In the package.json file add dependency to massive:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "massive": "^6.10.2"
  }
```

Then follow instructions from [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) to get the connection string of postgres and use that in the code you shared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hesitant to do that because I assumed that creating an Express application in a microservice kind of defeated the point. Are there any drawbacks to using Express in a Cloud Function like that?

Comment: No there isnt. Node.js is well supported platform for the same.